# Getting error when using image link to draw on canvas rather than importing it (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, canvas

Basically, I have some code that I wrote and it takes an image and draws it on the canvas however when I use an image link instead, the app breaks down and turns white with an error in the console saying "Process is not defined".

**This is the code with the image directly imported**

```
import image from '../images/leaf-spot-disease.jpg'

const Testing = () => {
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);

  const handleImageLoad = useCallback(() => {
    setImageLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  const imageRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(imageLoaded) {
      const image = imageRef.current
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    canvas.width = 100
    canvas.height = 100

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.drawImage(image , 0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height)
    
    console.log(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height).data.length)
    }
     
  }, [imageLoaded])

  return (
    <>
      <img src={image} alt="" className={styles.theImage} ref={imageRef} onLoad={handleImageLoad}/>
      <canvas className={styles.canvasCont} ref={canvasRef}>

      </canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

With the above way it works perfectly but the moment I use a link instead of importing an image like the example below the app breaks

```
const image = "https://storage.googleapis.com/object-cut-images/54062ac7-59dd-4684-baf4-840e6c5a2c3c.png"
```

When image is imported it works perfectly and when I use the above code it does not work again and nothing gets drawn on the canvas and also the page turns full white with that process is not defined error.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined @Konrad

Comment: You have to find the place that causes the error and fix it

Comment: That is the problem I have no idea where that error is coming from because when I import the image instead of using the link it works perfectly well

Comment: Usually there is file and line number with the error message

Comment: Solved it, I just updated react-scripts and got rid of that error (The  process was not defined) I have a ton of errors now but at least I understand those